# integer division vs regular division

Tags: c, double, long-integer, sieve

I need to compare an integer in a loop to the quotient of a `long` and a `long`. in order to not do integer division, if I understand correctly do I need to convert one of the longs into a double?

```
long prime = primes[d];
int i = 1;

//  "inputNumber / prime" should not be integer division, while it is now.
//  How do I do this yet still compare it to an "int" afterwards? 
while (i < (inputNumber / prime))
{
    primes[i*prime] = 0;
    i++;
}
```

That's the code snippet. `primes` is an array filled with `long`s. Btw is this code correct:

```
primes[i*prime] = 0;
```

because I am worried that a `long * int` won't work for an array index.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't accept too hastily ... Oli's answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply one of the operands of the integer division by `1.0` to avoid integer truncation of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `while((i * prime) < inputNumber)` instead?  A `long` multiplied by an `int` results in a `long`...

Comment: Not only that, but since `i*prime` is immediately used as an index, it doesn't have to be recalculated. Of course there is a question of overflow (but there already was).